# View all requests on Google Cloud Console?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

I just started using Google Cloud Console.

Even without creating any instance either on Compute Engine or App Engine, I see few request received by Google on my project. I am guessing these are the calls made by Google to set up my project. Found them on the main project [homepage](https://console.developers.google.com/project).

Is there a way for me to see all requests Google received for my project?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For Google Compute Engine, you can access them by going to "Operations". You can click on the Operation to get details about it.

[image]

Comment: I did check this section, there are no requests I made. I didn't even create any instance on Compute Engine or App Engine, but I still see some requests spike on the Overview Dashboard. I guess those are requests made by Google to setup the project or change some settings. Thanks!